# Lyft API ride request returning 403 in sandbox environment

Tags: api, sandbox, lyft-api

I'm all of a sudden getting a 403 "Sandbox is not supported for this endpoint" when hitting the Lyft Ride Request endpoint using the sandbox token. Does anybody know if Lyft is changing their API?

#### Request:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://api.lyft.com/v1/rides \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer <sandbox_access_token>' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"ride_type" : "lyft", "origin" : {"lat" : 37.77663, "lng" : -122.39227 },  "destination" : {"lat" : 37.771, "lng" : -122.39123, "address" : "Mission Bay Boulevard North" } }'
```

#### Response:

```
{
    "error_description": "Sandbox is not supported for this endpoint",
    "error": "forbidden"
}
```

Comment: I've also noticed that right now, no sandbox page exist in Lyft developers docs. Does it mean that it doesn't work anymore? Also Even without any successful ride request, there was a try to make a transaction from a card that was registered.

Answer (score 1):

Lyft released an [announcement](https://developer.lyft.com/docs/announcements#section-ride-request-sandbox-deprecation) about this:

> ### Ride Request Sandbox Deprecation
>
> On May 18th, 2018 Sandbox was deprecated for Ride Request API endpoints. Specifically, the Sandbox Ride Status endpoint was deprecated.
>
> Production access tokens can still be used to test all endpoints. However, keep in mind that testing the Ride Request endpoint with a Production token will incur costs as this is a standard Lyft ride request call.
>
> Thank you,
>
> The Lyft Ride Request API Team

This is a huge bummer, as testing the functionality of the ride state is hugely important to the development of my app, and I'm not sure how to proceed without this feature on their API.